# Why snapping doesn't work on Leaflet version 1.0.0 and newer?

Tags: leaflet, leaflet-draw

On documentation of Leaflet.Draw, Snapping sample is not working with Leaflet 1.0 but it works with Leaflet 0.7

http://leaflet.github.io/Leaflet.draw/docs/leaflet-draw-latest.html#l-draw-polyline

Is it supposed to be works with different method?

Comment: Snapping you are referring to is done with the help of `Leaflet.Snap` plugin which does not work correctly with the latest Leaflet. If you are not tied to `Leaflet.Draw` plugin, you could try `Leaflet.PM` plugin for drawing, which has snapping bulit in. See demo at https://geoman.io/studio/

Comment: Thanks @TomazicM ,
But for sorry i am tied to Leaflet.Draw plugin, and using Leaflet.PM plugin will require to re-build the whole drawing functions of the web map that i'm working on.